# Winsock nonblocking send() wait buffer. What is the correct method?

Tags: c++, buffer, winsock, send, nonblocking

I have some questions about when it is needed to store the data in the wait buffer (waiting for the FD_WRITE event).

This is my send function (fixed):

```
bool MyClass::DataSend(char *buf, int len)
{
    if (len <=0 || m_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET) return false;

    if (m_SendBufferLen > 0)
    {
        if ((m_SendBufferLen + len) < MAX_BUFF_SIZE)
        {
            memcpy((m_SendBuffer + m_SendBufferLen), buf, len);
            m_SendBufferLen += len;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // close the connection and log insuficient wait buffer size
            return false;
        }
    }

    int iResult;
    int nPosition = 0;
    int nLeft = len;

    while (true)
    {
        iResult = send(m_Socket, (char*)(buf + nPosition), nLeft, 0);

        if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (iResult > 0)
            {
                nPosition   += iResult;
                nLeft       -= iResult;

            }
            else
            {
                // log 0 bytes sent
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                if ((m_SendBufferLen + nLeft) < MAX_BUFF_SIZE)
                {
                    // log data copied to the wait buffer
                    memcpy((m_SendBuffer + m_SendBufferLen), (buf + nPosition), nLeft);
                    m_SendBufferLen += nLeft;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // close the connection and log insuficient wait buffer size
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // close the connection and log winsock error
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (nLeft <= 0) break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My send (FD_WRITE event) function (fixed):

```
bool MyClass::DataSendEvent()
{
    if (m_SendBufferLen < 1) return true;

    int iResult;
    int nPosition = 0;
    int nLeft = m_SendBufferLen;

    while (true)
    {
        iResult = send(m_Socket, (char*)(m_SendBuffer + nPosition), nLeft, 0);

        if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (iResult > 0)
            {
                nPosition   += iResult;
                nLeft       -= iResult;
            }
            else
            {
                // log 0 bytes sent
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                if (nPosition > 0)
                {
                    memmove(m_SendBuffer, (m_SendBuffer + nPosition), (m_SendBufferLen - nPosition));
                    m_SendBufferLen -= nPosition;
                }

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // close the connection and log winsock error
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (nLeft <= 0)
        {
            if (m_SendBufferLen == nPosition)
            {
                m_SendBufferLen = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                memmove(m_SendBuffer, (m_SendBuffer + nPosition), (m_SendBufferLen - nPosition));
                m_SendBufferLen -= nPosition;
                nPosition   = 0;
                nLeft       = m_SendBufferLen;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Do I really need the `if (nPosition > 0)` or not? How do I simulate this scenario? Is there possible send() in non-blocking mode send less bytes than the requested? If not, why using the while() looping?

- This is the final code (thanks to @user315052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your while loop, you are already decrementing `nLeft`, so you don't need to subtract `nPosition` from it.

```
iResult = send(m_Socket, (char*)(buf + nPosition), nLeft, 0);
```

In your second function, when you are shifting the unsent bytes to the beginning of the array, you should use `memmove`, since you have overlapped regions (you are copying a region of `m_SendBuffer` into itself). The overlap is illustrated below, where some of the `A`'s would get copied onto itself.

```
m_SendBuffer: [XXXXAAAAAAAAAAAA]
mPosition: 4
nLeft: 12
```

I am a little confused about why `DataSend()` is implemented to allow the caller to keep calling it with success even when the `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` is encountered. I would suggest the interface be modified to return a result that lets the caller know that it should stop sending, and to wait for an indication to resume sending.

You don't need the `nPosition > 0` check.

You can force the case to occur by having the receiver of the data not read anything.

It is definitely possible for `send` in non-blocking mode to send fewer bytes than requested.

Comment: Thanks man. The reason of DataSend() allow the caller to keep calling is because this is a Game Server and did not process the requests by himself, so he send the data to another process that connect to SQL database, etc. The Game Server waits for the external process response to allow the player to login, etc.

Comment: Hi, please check if my send (FD_WRITE event) at first post is correct. I have made the fixes in the first function too...

Comment: Another question. I need to use memmove instead of memcpy for the reposition of the buffer in the `DataSendEvent()` ?

Comment: @youngrp: In `DataSendEvent`, use `memmove`, not `memcpy`. I updated the post, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Just need to change `memcpy` to `memmove` and every else is fine ? What do you think ?

Comment: I don't see anything else obvious. Good luck!

Comment: I am a little confused about the overlapped regions that you said... If the `Dst*` will be always the start of the buffer, and the `Src*` will aways be at least one byte ahead of the start, why can be overlapped ? I have made some tests and works fine with `memcpy`...

 char buffer[] = "Text1Text2Text3Text4Text5Text6Text7Text8Text9Text10";
 int size = sizeof(buffer);

 printf_s("%s\n", buffer);

 for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
 {
  memcpy(buffer, (buffer + 5), (size - 5));
  size -= 5;
  printf_s("%s\n", buffer);
 }

Comment: @youngrp: I illustrated the overlap in the post. `memcpy` *might* work, but the documentation to `memcpy` will definitely say the regions are not to overlap. If you want to be sure the code will *always* work, you should use `memmove`. Regards.

Comment: I understand, but this dont make any sense if Dst is aways lower than Src in my code. Follow the `memmove()` source: [link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/memmove.c.htm) . As you can see, if the Dst if lower then Src the function returns to `memcpy()`...

Comment: @youngrp: I can't make you change your code, I'm not your boss. I don't write my code to how the library is implemented, but to how it is documented. This gives me a better likelihood that my code will still work if I move to a different system, or the library is upgraded. Regards.

Comment: Take it easy man... I'm not questioning your knowledge. Thank you very much for your help and sorry if I said something bad.

Comment: @youngrp: No problems. I didn't mean to come off as angry, because I'm not. Regards.